# How to use random string as route parameter (ExpressJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express

I am implementing reset password by having the random string in the url path as a route parameter. I later use it in app.param. When the random string contains the character '/' app doesn't work properly. Following is my implementation

in models/mymodelname.js

```
resetId = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('base64');
```

in routes/mymodelname.js

```
app.post('/resetpassword/:resetId',users.resetPassword);
```

Is there any way I can use my resetId got from random string to be used as route parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of ways that you could solve this issue:

1. Use the [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) function to convert the problem characters into their `%XX` representation:

   ```
   resetId = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('base64');
   // ...
   resetIdEscaped = encodeURIComponent(resetId);
   // Example: L73jflJreR%2FuivSdnMU5%2Fg%3D%3D
   ```
2. Use hex encoding instead of base64 encoding when converting the [buffer](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) to a string:

   ```
   resetId = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex');
   // Example: 13e095f8967a1ba06d11eeeed616051d
   ```